# I am working on PassThrough driver sample in win 10 x86 but it does not print anything using KdPrint. Why?

Tags: driver

I print using KdPrint(("Hi\n")); in FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
    PtPreOperationPassThrough(
    *Inout* PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    *In* PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext
    ) and seeing what happens in DebugView Program after open a file . The driver is started as I use driverquery. But I see no output after opening files randomly.

the below exists in my code:

```
CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {
{ IRP_MJ_CREATE,
0,
PtPreOperationPassThrough,
PtPostOperationPassThrough },
{ IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL,
0,
PtPreOperationPassThrough,
PtPostOperationPassThrough },

{ IRP_MJ_CLEANUP,
0,
PtPreOperationPassThrough,
PtPostOperationPassThrough },

{ IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};

//
//  This defines what we want to filter with FltMgr
```

//

```
CONST FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration = {

sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),         //  Size
FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,           //  Version
0,                                  //  Flags

NULL,                               //  Context
Callbacks,                          //  Operation callbacks

PtUnload,                           //  MiniFilterUnload

PtInstanceSetup,                    //  InstanceSetup
PtInstanceQueryTeardown,            //  InstanceQueryTeardown
PtInstanceTeardownStart,            //  InstanceTeardownStart
PtInstanceTeardownComplete,         //  InstanceTeardownComplete

NULL,                               //  GenerateFileName
NULL,                               //  GenerateDestinationFileName
NULL                                //  NormalizeNameComponent

};


NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
_In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
)

{
NTSTATUS status;

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

PT_DBG_PRINT(PTDBG_TRACE_ROUTINES,
    ("PassThrough!DriverEntry: Entered\n"));

//
//  Register with FltMgr to tell it our callback routines
//

status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject,
    &FilterRegistration,
    &gFilterHandle);

FLT_ASSERT(NT_SUCCESS(status));

if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

    //
    //  Start filtering i/o
    //

    status = FltStartFiltering(gFilterHandle);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {

        FltUnregisterFilter(gFilterHandle);
    }
}

return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

passThrough sample uses DbgPrint. It could be captured with DbgView.

1) modify this line in your project

```
ULONG gTraceFlags = 0;
```

as

```
ULONG gTraceFlags = 3;
```

2) comment this line

```
//FLT_ASSERT( NT_SUCCESS( status ) );
```

3) rebuild project

4) run this command line in admin mode and reboot

```
Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

5) run DebugView and turn on 
"Capture Kernel"
"Enable Verbose Kernel Output"

4) try using comprehensivce OSR Driver loader to register and load driver .sys file